# TextField onValueChange - Announce Additional Semantics

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, semantics

Using a custom `TextField` implementation, but it still uses the `BasicTextField` provided by compose.

```
BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {
            this.contentDescription = (contentDescription
                ?: "") + (if (!placeholder.isNullOrBlank() && value.isBlank()) placeholder
                else value) + counterText
            if (disabled) {
               disabled()
            }
        },
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { newValue ->
        onValueChange(newValue)
    },
    enabled = enabled,
    readOnly = readOnly,
    textStyle = mergedTextStyle,
    cursorBrush = SolidColor(contentColor),
    keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
    keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    singleLine = singleLine,
    maxLines = maxL,
    minLines = minL
) {...
```

The semantics read exactly as I would like them to on original focus. But when I type a character all it reads is that character.

key entered, `A` = `“A”`.

I would like the semantics to announce `“A, ${counterText}”`. But I can’t find a way to tie into what looks to be the `TextInputService` or something similar to that. Is there a concept I’m missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what I was looking for. It’s annoying because I can’t seem to find examples on the Compose Developer instructions, but it works pretty well.

```
Modifier.semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {
    …
    liveRegion = LiveRegionMode.Polite // ..Assertive if you want immediate response on change.
}
```

With this the Text will say `”A, $stateDescription, $contentDescription”`